# Handling Forms Authentication events in a HTTP Module

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, forms-authentication, httpmodule

I'm creating a HTTP module by implementing [`IHttpModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and I'd like to handle the [`Authenticate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.security.formsauthenticationmodule.authenticate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event, raised by the Forms Authentication module.

The documentation only states how to handle this event from within Global.asax, how can I handle this event from within my HTTP module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the [`AuthenticateRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.authenticaterequest(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the `HttpApplication` that is passed to the `Init` method of your `IHttpModule` implementation:

```
// IHttpModule.Init
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    // subscribe to the AuthenticateRequest event
    context.AuthenticateRequest += this.onApplicationAuthenticateRequest;
}

private void onApplicationAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your code goes here
}
```

[This article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication) has an example of the basic authentication in Web API which uses custom HttpModule, might be helpful.

Comment: Ah - the documentation does explain that the `Authenticate` event is raised during the `AuthenticateRequest` event, but I overlooked that - thanks.